# CodeIgniter parse errors display but not written to log

Tags: apache, codeigniter, logging, error-handling, codeigniter-2

I'm attempting to build an error handling service for my CodeIgniter apps, and everything is logged as expected except parse errors. For example,

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /var/www/foo/web/app/controllers/foo.php`

... will output and get logged *by Apache* under E_ALL. All other (non-parse) errors get passed to the `log_exception` extension I've written in `/core/MY_Exceptions.php`, and show up in CI's logs with PHP 5.2.17 and 5.3.6 (MAMP). Parse errors will display in Apache's native error log, but NOT in CodeIgniter's logs – they seem to miss CodeIgniter altogether.

How can I ensure that parse errors get picked up by CI? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This may help you: [Why is codeigniter not logging error!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277751/why-is-codeigniter-not-logging-error)**

> If the page is failing to load because of a parse error, then it'll
>   never execute
>
> ```
> error_reporting(E_ALL);
> ```
>
> so you script will never know to output the error. Edit your php.ini
>   file to make sure you have:
>
> ```
> error_reporting = E_ALL
> error_log = "/path/to/some/apache/writable/file"
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense, and it also seems like there's no way to catch the error at the application level if it never runs in the first place. Which is a bummer.

Comment: yeah it breaks the flow and makes it difficult to log.